# swift - Custom UITableViewCell doesn't display content added in Storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, cocoa-touch

I decided to declare a custom UITableViewCell class with xib to make it easier to control the background of my cell, since it needs to be different depending on cells position in the table.

This works fine, but when I try to add extra views to my custom cell in the Storyboard they are not displayed, only the original custom cell.

Here is my custom cell class:

```
class GlTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {


    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code


        let bgView: UIView = UIView()
        bgView.backgroundColor = .clear

        self.backgroundView = bgView
        self.backgroundColor = .clear

    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

    func isFirst() {

        //Top

        let topLeftCornerImageView = self.viewWithTag(101) as! UIImageView

        let topLineImageView = self.viewWithTag(102) as! UIImageView

        let topRightCornerImageView = self.viewWithTag(103) as! UIImageView

        topLeftCornerImageView.image = UIImage(named: "cellTopLeftCorner")

        topLineImageView.image = UIImage(named: "cellTopLine")

        topRightCornerImageView.image = UIImage(named: "cellTopRightCorner")



        //Bottom

        let bottomLeftCornerImageView = self.viewWithTag(201) as! UIImageView

        let bottomLineImageView = self.viewWithTag(202) as! UIImageView

        let bottomRoghtCornerImageView = self.viewWithTag(203) as! UIImageView

        bottomLeftCornerImageView.image = UIImage(named: "cellLeftLine")

        bottomLineImageView.image = UIImage(named: "cellBackgroundFill")

        bottomRoghtCornerImageView.image = UIImage(named: "cellRightLine")

    }

    func isLast() {


        //Top

        let topLeftCornerImageView = self.viewWithTag(101) as! UIImageView

        let topLineImageView = self.viewWithTag(102) as! UIImageView

        let topRightCornerImageView = self.viewWithTag(103) as! UIImageView

        topLeftCornerImageView.image = UIImage(named: "cellLeftLine")

        topLineImageView.image = UIImage(named: "cellBackgroundFill")

        topRightCornerImageView.image = UIImage(named: "cellRightLine")



        //Bottom

        let bottomLeftCornerImageView = self.viewWithTag(201) as! UIImageView

        let bottomLineImageView = self.viewWithTag(202) as! UIImageView

        let bottomRoghtCornerImageView = self.viewWithTag(203) as! UIImageView

        bottomLeftCornerImageView.image = UIImage(named: "cellBottomLeftCorner")

        bottomLineImageView.image = UIImage(named: "cellBottomLine")

        bottomRoghtCornerImageView.image = UIImage(named: "cellBottomRightCorner")
    }

    func isSingle() {

        //Top

        let topLeftCornerImageView = self.viewWithTag(101) as! UIImageView

        let topLineImageView = self.viewWithTag(102) as! UIImageView

        let topRightCornerImageView = self.viewWithTag(103) as! UIImageView

        topLeftCornerImageView.image = UIImage(named: "cellTopLeftCorner")

        topLineImageView.image = UIImage(named: "cellTopLine")

        topRightCornerImageView.image = UIImage(named: "cellTopRightCorner")


        //Bottom

        let bottomLeftCornerImageView = self.viewWithTag(201) as! UIImageView

        let bottomLineImageView = self.viewWithTag(202) as! UIImageView

        let bottomRoghtCornerImageView = self.viewWithTag(203) as! UIImageView

        bottomLeftCornerImageView.image = UIImage(named: "cellBottomLeftCorner")

        bottomLineImageView.image = UIImage(named: "cellBottomLine")

        bottomRoghtCornerImageView.image = UIImage(named: "cellBottomRightCorner")



    }

    func isMiddle() {
        let topLeftCornerImageView = self.viewWithTag(101) as! UIImageView

        let topLineImageView = self.viewWithTag(102) as! UIImageView

        let topRoghtCornerImageView = self.viewWithTag(103) as! UIImageView

        let bottomLeftCornerImageView = self.viewWithTag(201) as! UIImageView

        let bottomLineImageView = self.viewWithTag(202) as! UIImageView

        let bottomRightCornerImageView = self.viewWithTag(203) as! UIImageView



        topLeftCornerImageView.image = UIImage(named: "cellLeftLine")

        topLineImageView.image = UIImage(named: "cellBackgroundFill")

        topRoghtCornerImageView.image = UIImage(named: "cellRightLine")


        bottomLeftCornerImageView.image = UIImage(named: "cellLeftLine")

        bottomLineImageView.image = UIImage(named: "cellBackgroundFill")

        bottomRightCornerImageView.image = UIImage(named: "cellRightLine")




    }

}
```

And here is my table vc:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        updateLabels()

        tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "GlTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "ProductCell")
    }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ProductCell", for: indexPath) as! GlTableViewCell

        cell.isSingle()
        return cell


..
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is your program crashing on `let topLeftCornerImageView = self.viewWithTag(101) as! UIImageView` ?

Comment: No, it doesn't, as long a I have this in my tableview controller: tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "GlTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "ProductCell")